# SVG using <embed>: css not picking up styles

Tags: html, css, object, svg, embed

Having looked at all the different methods of using SVGs, I'm unable to affect the fill colour using CSS when using 'embed', and I can't figure out why. It renders the SVG, but I can't affect it via CSS.

If I paste the SVG code inline, fill colour change via CSS works - but if I reference a file direct, eg:

```
<embed src="my-svg-file.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
```

..then regardless of how I target the element (either the svg or even the path attribute of the svg file) it won't pick up any CSS changes.

Inspecting it tells me that the browser is not picking *any* styles for the svg element.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="close">
                      <embed src="icon-close.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
</a>
```

which generates the following in the browser:

```
<a class="close" href="#">
<embed src="icon-close.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
<svg id="Layer_1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#4D4D4D" d="M1.171,20c-0.292,0-0.585-0.111-0.809-0.334c-0.448-0.447-0.449-1.172-0.003-1.619l8.022-8.045L0.349,1.968 c-0.448-0.447-0.448-1.172,0-1.62c0.447-0.447,1.171-0.447,1.618,0l8.032,8.031l8.02-8.042c0.446-0.449,1.172-0.449,1.62-0.002 c0.448,0.447,0.448,1.171,0.002,1.62L11.618,10l8.033,8.033c0.447,0.447,0.447,1.172,0,1.619c-0.447,0.446-1.172,0.446-1.619,0 l-8.03-8.031l-8.02,8.043C1.758,19.888,1.464,20,1.171,20z">
</svg>
</embed>
</a>
```

So you'd think that since the svg element (and subsequent path element) is generated, then a CSS file targetting it should be valid, eg:

```
a.close svg {
fill: #007393; 
}
```

I've tried all variations, eg including the path element, the embed element, both, etc, but no joy.

Using 'object' is no better.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: CSS only operates on one document. embed/object is a separate document so you need to put the CSS for the embedded image in the image itself (or link to it from the embedded image). Setting CSS styles in the parent document have no effect in the embedded document.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<embed>` to import SVG it is not the best solution. It won't let you edit any properties via CSS although you see it in your web inspector.

There are other ways to import your SVG but embedding your SVG inline (like: `<svg>...</svg>`) is the only way you can style it with a CSS in the host document. Otherwise it needs an embedded style or stylesheet link in the embedded document.

So in your case,

```css
a.close svg path {
  fill: #007393; 
}
```

```html
<a class="close" href="#">
  <svg id="Layer_1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="#4D4D4D" d="M1.171,20c-0.292,0-0.585-0.111-0.809-0.334c-0.448-0.447-0.449-1.172-0.003-1.619l8.022-8.045L0.349,1.968 c-0.448-0.447-0.448-1.172,0-1.62c0.447-0.447,1.171-0.447,1.618,0l8.032,8.031l8.02-8.042c0.446-0.449,1.172-0.449,1.62-0.002 c0.448,0.447,0.448,1.171,0.002,1.62L11.618,10l8.033,8.033c0.447,0.447,0.447,1.172,0,1.619c-0.447,0.446-1.172,0.446-1.619,0 l-8.03-8.031l-8.02,8.043C1.758,19.888,1.464,20,1.171,20z">
  </svg>
</a>
```

You also have to select `path`to fill an element and you will be overriding `#4D4D4D` fill.

Comment: Well you can style the embedded SVG with CSS, you just have to link the CSS in the embedded document itself. What you're trying to say is that you can't do cross-document styling.

Comment: Yes I meant that. Hope now is explained better. Thanks Robert.

Comment: I've changed a few words to try to make it clearer still, hope that's OK.